# Possible range of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose there is a function, 
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + x^2}$$
And we have to find its domain and range.
So first I calculated the domain:-

Since the denominator of f(x) is always greater than 0 for all x belongs to Real numbers(R).
So the domain of the function is the set of real numbers i.e.
$$domain(f) = R$$
Then to find the range I did the following:-
Let $$y = f(x)$$. Then,
$$y = f(x)$$
$$y = \frac{x}{1 + x^2}$$
$$x^2y-x+y=0$$
$$x^2-\frac{x}{y}+1=0$$
Then, By quadratic formula:-
$$x=\frac{\frac{1}{y}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}-4}}{2}$$
Solving which we get:-
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$
Clearly x will get real values, if
$$1-4y^2\ge0$$ $$and$$ $$y\ne0$$
Implies that, $$4y^2-1\le0 \quad \text{and} \quad y\ne0$$
Implies that, $$y^2-\frac{1}{4}\le0 \quad \text{and} \quad y\ne0$$
Implies that, $$(y-\frac{1}{2})(y+\frac{1}{2})\le0 \quad \text{and} \quad y\ne0$$
Implies that, $$-\frac{1}{2}\le y\le\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad y\ne0$$
Implies that, $$y\in \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right] - \{0\}$$

This means that the set of range contains all real values from -1/2 to 1/2 excluding 0 and the domain contains all the real values.
Since the domain contains all the real values so when we put x = 0 in f(x) then we get 0 but the set of range does not contain 0.
How is this possible, what am I missing?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason the domain cannot be the rational numbers? Or complex numbers?

Comment: "Is there any reason the domain cannot be the rational numbers? Or complex numbers?"  Or the integers, or even numbers, or {5,7,13}?  I think this depends on texts.  A lot of high school texts, ask to find "domains" as "all the possible real numbers that can go be legitimate input to the function".  This kind of drives me nuts because that is *not* the meaning of domain at all.  But then that isn't the OP's fault, and the OP is clearly reasoning correctly *as his/her text instruct* (which is the wrong way to reason but... not the OP's fault).

Comment: If $x = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ so if $0$ is in the domain, then $0$ is in the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. However, you've missed something. When you solved $yx^2-x+y=0$, because you used the quadratic formula, you implicitly assumed that that was a quadratic equation. *That* is the reason you're getting $y\neq0$ as part of your constraints. The original equation is very much solvable for $y=0$, so $\{0\}$ is contained in the range.

Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: Those of you who say that I have used quadratic formula incorrectly I want to mention that I have taken $$y\ne0$$ because in the equation
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$ y cant be 0 because it is in denominator

Comment: @CaptainCode You've used the quadratic formula correctly. However, $yx^2-x+y=0$ _isn't always a quadratic equation_ (specifically, when $y=0$ the equation reads $-x=0$), and in that case, your approach of interpreting it as a quadratic equation is wrong. You have to split your argument into two cases depending on whether $y=0$ or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply now I got the point.

Comment: Now what if I divide the equation by y that is:- $$x^2y-x+y=0$$ $$x^2-\frac{x}{y}+1$$ Now it is definitely a quadratic equation so now I used the quadratic formula in it, which gives.
Then, By quadratic formula:-
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$

Comment: I have modified my question now try to answwr it.

Answer (score 2):

You assumed $y \neq 0$ when using the quadratic formula, so you have to consider the case $y=0$ separately. There's no problem in making assumptions during the calculation to make it easier, but you do have to go back and examine what happens when the assumptions don't hold.

Answer (score 0):

"Then, by quadratic formula"... you divided the stuff by $y$, assuming $y\neq 0$, which is incorrect.

A faster and more efficient approach:

When $x=0$, $y = 0$. Otherwise, we divide the numerator and the denominator by $x$ at the same time, and we get $y = \frac{1}{x+1/x}$. Now it turns out that we only need to consider the function $x+1/x$. This is no difficult task. Simply invoking $x+1/x \geq 2, x >0$, $x+1/x \leq -2, x <0$ will do.

Comment: Those of you who say that I have used quadratic formula incorrectly I want to mention that I have taken $$y\ne0$$ because in the equation
$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$ y cant be 0 because it is in denominator

Comment: You have taken $y$ not zero. And that's what exactly you asked. You may also use Wolfram alpha to plot.